# Make Liferay use Oracle sequences for its entities primary key generation

Tags: sql, oracle11g, liferay, primary-key, liferay-6

We are developing some portlets which are going to be deployed on **Liferay 6.2.x** using **Oracle 11g** database.

We have implemented some services which invoke Liferay create user service.

As far as I know on our Liferay don't use Oracle sequences for its primary key generation (and uses `select max(id)+1 from table` strategy), which is so slow on very large user-bases (we have 10M+ users, and the services creates millions of users in a batch).

Is there any way to make liferay use oracle sequences internally for its internal entities' primary key generation?

Answer (score 1):

First: Did you measure (and can you confirm) that this is slow? The way you ask your question sounds like you just assume that this is your bottleneck.

Next: Liferay's counter generation should not involve a new select per each created object (in order to generate the new ID. If you look at portal.properties, which you can override in portal-ext.properties, you'll find this section:

```
##
## Counter
##

#
# The counter operates with its own data source to prevent deadlocks. By
# default, the data source created for the counter uses the same settings as
# those used to create the data source used for the rest of the portal. That
# happens because the counter service will look up the properties prefixed
# with "jdbc.default." to create its data source. See the JDBC properties
# prefixed with "jdbc.default." for more information.
#
# Setting a different value for the counter JDBC prefix allows you to better
# fine tune the counter data source with its own set of configuration
# settings for high availability installations. Note that these settings,
# though separate, are a copy of the default settings with the newly
# overridden values.
#
counter.jdbc.prefix=jdbc.default.

#
# Set the number of increments between database updates to the Counter
# table. Set this value to a higher number for better performance.
#
counter.increment=100

#
# You can further fine tune the counter increment for specific counter
# names. This entry will ensure that the counter name
# "com.liferay.portal.model.Layout" or anything that starts with
# "com.liferay.portal.model.Layout#" will only increment by 1.
#
counter.increment.com.liferay.portal.model.Layout=1
```

When you take a look at Liferay's [user creation](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.1-ga2/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/UserLocalServiceImpl.java#L725), you'll find that id generation is done by CounterLocalService. You can either look at that implementation, but my recommendation is to not change such a central service. However, your mileage may vary.

IMHO you should profile your user creation and check what's your actual bottleneck and fix it. It might be the number of transactions, it might be something else that is happening during this operation (e.g. selecting roles, groups, etc.).

Note also that Liferay can operate with user import on-demand, e.g. that's one mode of operation for the LDAP interface: You can just connect to LDAP without any actual user imports. Users will be imported the moment they log in. If you have millions of users, they probably don't sign in at the same time, so you'll spread out the load automatically. If you implement something like LDAP or actually just load your users into an LDAP server is your decision.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement:

I have a liferay entity (log table) that has a primary key auto generated by Liferay.

However now an external application need to add entries to this same db table.

**Looking at this requirement I see only two options:**

1. If I can change the table to use MySQL generated primary key, then
   Liferay or External application both can add entries without any
   worries.
2. If #1 is not possible, then only option is to expose this
   entity using a liferay web services for the external application to add entries to this db table.